# query to select cityname

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

There are two database tables. One is city which contains columns such as stateid, cityid and cityname and other is state having columns named stateid and statename.

```
select * from city where stateid in (
    select stateid
    from states
    where statename in ('uttar pradesh','haryana')
    )
```

I am not getting the record showing the cities of Haryana and Uttar Pradesh.

Comment: ' cities of Haryana and Uttar Pradesh ' - not local but aren't these states?

Comment: Haryana and Uttar Pradesh ka states but the query is relating two databases city and states to show the cities of both of the states

Comment: Query should produce correct result. Please add sample data as text.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please before you publish look at the formatted version of your post. Please read the edit help re fomatting.

Answer (score 0):

do check the state name that you are passing in query is same as stored in database. MySql will perform case sensitive search.

Comment: 'MySql will perform case sensitive search.; - not necessarily although it is true that the question uses camel case in the state names but query does not.